# Timeout in node.js request

Tags: linux, node.js, request

I wonder how does `node.js request` module work in regard to `timeout` parameter.

What happens after `timeout` time period have passed? I.e:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    url: Theurl,
    timeout: 300000
};

request(options, function(error, resp, body) {...
```

What happens after `300000`? Does request try to request the url again or not?

I also found that `Linux Kernel` have a default 20 sec `TCP socket connection timeout.` (http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout)
Does it mean that `timeout` option in `request` will be max 20 sec (if I dont change the `Linux Kernel timeout`), regardless of what I set in `options`?
I use `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request` returns error with error code set as stated in [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#timeouts) readme (timeout section).

Take a look at [TIME_WAIT](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html) details.

But yes, kernel will cut it down with its configuration. As stated in your link, you can change it by chaning `tcp_syn_retries`.

Answer (score 5):

From the readme of the request package:

```
Note that if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, 
the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option
```

So in your case, the request will be aborted after 20 sec. The request won't try to request the url again (even if the timeout is set to a lower value than 20000). You would have to write your own logic for this or use another package, such as [requestretry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestretry).

Example:

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://www.gooooerererere.com/',
    timeout: 5000
}

var maxRequests = 5;

function requestWithTimeout(attempt){
    request(options, function(error,response,body){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);

            if(attempt==maxRequests)
                return;
            else
                requestWithTimeout(attempt+1);
        }
        else {
            //do something with result
        }
    });
}

requestWithTimeout(1);
```

You can also check for a specific error message, such as ETIMEDOUT, with

```
if(error.code == [ERROR_MESSAGE])
```

Comment: You could wait for the error (request timed out) and make the call a second time. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Ok. yes please make an example, it would be very kind! Then I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Basically I want to retry if `request` does not success to connect.

Comment: Looks good, but would you recommend to use `requestretry` maybe instead?

Comment: I don't like to use too many packages, but it could make life easier yeah :) And it has more functionality and reliability of course.

Comment: Is it possible to use all the `request` options in `request-retry?`

Comment: Yes, you can use all the options from the request package options.

Comment: Can I ask you a question in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96862/discussion-between-piscator-and-user1665355).

Answer (score 0):

If timeout happens, your callback function will be executed with error set to message 'Error: ETIMEDOUT'.

This little project https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-request-retry provides ready-to-use, configured wrapper for making retries triggered by many connection error codes, timeout included.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to retry until `request` do success?

Comment: Take a look at this project: [link](https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-request-retry). It's a wrapper for request, with configured retry delay and number of retry attempts to be made before finally giving up.